# Why are the seats of pedicabs so sloped? Wouldn't people slide off?

Tags: rickshaw

This is a "rickshaw" common to the streets of Dhaka:

[image]

My question is, why do all pedicabs/Bangladeshi rickshaws of this design seem to be sloping forward. The seat is tilted forward, and especially the footrest tilts forward. Wouldn't this design result in people sliding forward off the seat?

What is the reason for this design?

Comment: Does the cab still tilt forward when somebody is sitting in it? I would expect there is a spring or some kind of suspension that makes it look more natural when under load.

Comment: There are elliptic leaf springs for the two rear wheels, so that could very well explain some of the initial angle. But you can see here: (https://i.imgur.com/emocuiK.png) that even with people sitting on it, the surface seems to be angle 10-15° forward.

Comment: @LoftusPifflewog that comment is half-way to an answer, might be worth posting below ?

Comment: What worries me more is the forward inclination of the passenger footrest. As a rearward tilt might enable some bracing against forward projection.

Comment: Perhaps (my spontaneous impression) is that it psychologically very disconcerting to be tilted backwards. When the seat is level, it would tilt backwards when going uphills or when you go over potholes and such, and you would get the scary feeling of falling over backwards. I made the experience when you work with people in a wheelchair where you sometimes have to tilt them backwards (to get over kerbs or doorsteps), if they don't expect the movement it can be extremely scary. I also tried that sitting in a wheelchair myself.